# Docker container (PHP + MongoDB extension + `phpdotenv`) mongodb/mongodb 1.9.0-alpha1 requires ext-mongodb ^1.10.0 -> it is missing from your system

Tags: php, mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I would like to have a running Docker container for PHP that can remotely interact with a MongoDB Atlas database.

I had hard-coded and manually fixed a custom Docker Image to get the MongoDB extension working. Now having problems extending this to include the `vlucas/phpdotenv` composer package. Researching other locations, it seems there are other ways to running separate `composer` container and mapping relevant drives:

https://hackernoon.com/get-composer-to-run-on-docker-container-a-how-to-guide-y86g36z7

But I cannot get this to run, using either the `php:8.0-apache` image or my own custom image.

The custom image is built as:

```
FROM php:8.0-apache

RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get upgrade -y && apt-get install git libssl-dev -y
RUN pecl install mongodb && docker-php-ext-enable mongodb
RUN echo "extension=mongodb.so" >> /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
COPY --from=composer /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer

EXPOSE 80 443
```

The `docker-compose.yml`, using my custom image above, is:

```
version: '2'

services:
  php:
    image: redswitch/php-mongodb:8.0-1.9.0-3
    container_name: php
    volumes:
      - ./html:/var/www/html
    restart: always
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=www.domain.com
      - LETSENCRYPT_HOST=www.domain.com
      - LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL=admin@domain.com
      - "TZ=Europe/London"
    ports:
      - 80
    expose:
      - 80
    restart: unless-stopped

  composer:
    image: composer:2.0
    command: ["composer", "install"]
    volumes:
      - ./html:/app

networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: nginx-proxy-net
```

In the `./html` location is `composer.json`:

```
{
    "require": {
        "mongodb/mongodb": "^1.9.0-alpha1",
        "vlucas/phpdotenv": "^5.3.0"
    }
}
```

I have tried different minimum versions, such as `^1.8.0`, `^1.9.0` and the above. This provides variances of the same error message depending upon which version is specified in the `composer.json` file.

The `composer` container starts and stops, as expected. This is the container's log:

```
No composer.lock file present. Updating dependencies to latest instead of installing from lock file. See https://getcomposer.org/install for more information.,
Loading composer repositories with package information,
Updating dependencies,
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.,
,
  Problem 1,
    - Root composer.json requires mongodb/mongodb ^1.9.0-alpha1 -> satisfiable by mongodb/mongodb[1.9.0-alpha1].,
    - mongodb/mongodb 1.9.0-alpha1 requires ext-mongodb ^1.10.0 -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's mongodb extension.,
,
To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:,
    - /usr/local/etc/php/php-cli.ini,
    - /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-sodium.ini,
    - /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-zip.ini,
You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.,
```

Checking the `php` container with a `phpinfo()` call, I can see that the MongoDB extension v1.9.0 is enabled, with a loaded config file and additional config at:

- /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
- /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-mongodb.ini, /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-sodium.ini

How do I overcome this issue?

Is this the correct way to deploy PHP+MongoDB+Composer+PHPDotEnv?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your composer.json

```
"provide" : {
    "ext-mongodb": "*"
}
```